# a url's response may be replaced by another url

Tags: android, android-async-http

I have two different domain urls named A.com and B.com.
This is the code to send request: the asyncHttpClient is the same one.

```
asyncHttpClient.post(context, "A.com", aParams, aResponseHandler);
asyncHttpClient.post(context, "B.com", bParams, bRsponseHandler);
```

There is a chance to happen: get "B.com" response in aResponseHandler, although it doesn't happen frequently. Why does it mistake the response ?

Whehter i perform either of them solely, it's ok.

[I find another guy has the same question.](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/818)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you linked on github seems to be closed.
The original poster wrote the following:

> in my local tests ，**no way to reproduce this problem**， but truly
>   happened.....

It seems unlikely that this would occur, and the issue cannot be reproduced. Personally, I wouldn't worry about this happening in your application. You could write a conditional statement to check and throw an exception if the wrong ResponseHandler is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it will happen. I have some logs in 'onSuccess' of the ResponseHandler to find the question.  `MyLog.i(" request =" + getRequestURI().toString() +" responseString=" + responseString );`  The requestURI is not match with the responseString.